# how to generate metadata for RPM repository in Artifactory

Tags: rpm, nexus, yum, artifactory

We generate RPMs in the process of our daily development and we these RPMs will be deployed into production environment.

All these RPMs will be stored in a local yum repository and we just use "yum install package" to install any RPMs.

We want to use either Artifactory or Nexus (only OSS versions)  to manage our packages as both can be used as YUM repositories and we are trying to evaluate both of them first.

I have installed Artifactory OSS version first to evaluate.

- Created a test repo
- uploaded a RPM file into that test repo
- Created a artifactory.repo with artifactory repository path in /etc/yum.repos.d

But, when I try to install that RPM using yum install  I am getting below error

```
http://artifactory-server:8080/artifactory/testrepo/repodata/primary.xml.gz: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/primary.xml.gz from artifactory: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I did understand the error, it was looking for metadata in that repository and its not present.

I did see an option of creating meta data automatically but, that seems to be only for PRO version.

That means can't we use Artifactory OSS as a yum repository? I think there should be a way to use it  as YUM repo at least with basic features. I think I am missing something here.

My questions:

1. Can't we generate metadata automatically with Artifactory OSS version? Can any one please let me know how to use Artifactory OSS version as a YUM repo ?
2. Which one is better for my requirement Artifactory/Nexus (open source versions)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who find this post - YUM is now supported natively in Nexus Repository Manager 3 OSS for free.

Comment: This is about JFrog Artifactory, not Sonatype Nexus

Comment: @jgifford25 To put it another way: Artifactory OSS doesn't support Yum, you need to buy the PRO version. As an equivalent alternative, NXRM 3 OSS does support Yum.

Answer (score 1):

[YUM repositories support](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/YUM+Repositories) exist only in Artifactory Pro.

Answer (score 1):

For opensource version, you have to use nexus oss, which [YUM plugin](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-oss/tree/master/plugins/yum) is provided.

So far, YUM repository is supported in [Artifactory Pro verion](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/YUM+Repositories) only.